Laravel 10 API bearer tokens for all users?
I started a new project using Laravel 10 Jetstream, Fortify an Sanctum. I managed to create a basic Restful API with bearer tokens that need to be used by my web app and clients connecting to it.
this is my route being used for guess users on my website, registered users on my website and API users with tokens
Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth:sanctum', 'api']], function () {
    Route::get('sample', [ApiController::class, 'sample'])->name('api.sample');
});

The other route I have that is only to be used by for registered users via web and users allowed to by using tokens.
Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth:sanctum', 'api']], function () {
 Route::get('download', [DownloadController::class, 'download'])->name('api.download');
});

Some of the routes that the website uses might need the login users ID. I could pass an extra parameter to the API or create a bearer token for each login user on my website and get their ID using auth()->user()->id
I'm not sure what is the best way or best practice to do this.

For web user do i create a bearer token for each user that doesn't expire. So i get their user id.
Create separate API for web and clients to get their user id? (more code to maintain)
or just pass an extra parameter to get user id.

I was leaning towards #1 create a bearer token for each user that doesn't expire. If #3 how do I make sure only my web app passes the user id? and not the client via their web app / postman.
any suggestions? Is there a better way to do this or what is the best practice? Thanks

Create separate API for web and clients to get their user id? - yes
more code to maintain - no, your business logic should be extracted out of your controllers, and should not care if it's being called by a web or api user. But your api routes should not mix with your web routes. Even if they are similar now, they might be in the future and you should not be limited to updating the api bc of your web.
